# Gearman workers still running after the job server and Supervisor have been shutdown

Tags: php, supervisord, gearman

I have shutdown Gearman, using the (echo shutdown ; sleep 0.1) | netcat 127.0.0.1 4730 -w 1 command. I've also stopped Supervisor using /etc/init.d/supervisord stop. However, when I run a ps -aux, there are Gearman workers still running (i.e. /usr/bin/php gearmanworker.php). If i try to kill the worker, a new one is spawned immediately afterwards. Is there another database or something I must wipe to properly shutdown Gearman and its workers?

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I keep reading this as "German workers ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the workers are getting respawned hints that `supervisord` is probably still running.  Good chance the `/etc/init.d` script isn't working for some reason.  Try to kill it with

```
sudo killall supervisord
```

Then check with

```
ps aux | grep supervisord
```

Another useful trick is

```
sudo supervisorctl
```

Which if it works means your supervisord is running, and lets you do all sorts of things with it.